# How do I turn off macro on a Nikon D7000?

Tags: nikon-d7000, camera-settings

I turned it on alright, but when it comes to switching it off, it wasn't as intuitive. Can't figure it out.

Comment: You could look in the manual: http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17008/~/user's-manual---d7000---guide-to-digital-photography

Comment: The link was broken when I asked the question atleast.

Comment: Nikon's web site isn't _usually_ broken. But in any case, I think this question is okay here, because explanation of what exactly "Macro" might mean on a DSLR (as opposed to a point and shoot) is a valuable concept.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably talking about the *Close-Up* scene mode. It only takes into effect when the mode-dial is at the SCENE position.

To get out of it, either choose another mode or change the scene mode. To change the scene mode, rotate the rear control-dial while the mode-dial is still at the SCENE position.

Answer (score 2):

To further explain the *macro* vs. *closeup* issue:

- **Close-up** means photographing with a **focus distance shorter than an arbitrary limit**. (To further add to the confusion, most people will naturally see the distance from the subject to the frontmost lens element, while **in photography distances are generally calculated from the film plane** — the physical location, depth-wise, of the sensor in the camera)
- **Macro refers to** having a **magnification ratio** (the proportion of the subject's actual size relative to that of the image as projected by the lens on the sensor) larger than another arbitrary limit, although a relatively more common definition involves **1:1 repoduction ratio and larger**.

Since **minimum focus distance is a function of the lens optics and the lens register** (the distance from the outermost edge of the mount to the film plane) **and so is the magnification ratio for a given distance**, it is understandable how no function on the camera will be able to enable close-up photography without tricks such as increasing the lens register by moving the sensor, adding extension tubes or corrective elements.

Most confusion appears to be due to the **misconcept perpetrated by most point and shoot cameras** featuring a close-up enabling feature and calling it macro mode: all other factors being equal, a shorter distance implies a bigger ratio, but it is firstmost a feature enabling you to stick the camera at a few centimeters from your subject. On every interchangeable lens camera currently on the market, the camera doesn't automatically implement the above tricks: **the "flower" mode is the full auto mode biased to prefer smaller apertures to enhance depth of field, which is gets critically smaller with magnification.**